# emberjs direct access to resource not working

Tags: ember.js, routes

I have 2 routes - sessions and session (because I want to present them in 2 different pages)

```
App.Router.map(function () {

    this.route("sessions", { path: "/sessions" });
    this.route("session", { path: "/sessions/:session_id" });
}
```

When I go to: `#/sessions` - I get a nice table that I drew, and when I click the link I made
in the handlebar view:

```
{{#each model}}
<tr>
     <td>{{#link-to 'session' this}}{{this.id}}{{/link-to}}</td>
</tr>
```

It works - the separate handlebars of the session is drawn

When I go directly to `#/sessions/4` I'm getting an error:

`Assertion Failed: You may not pass "undefined" as id to the store's find method`

The routes:

```
App.SessionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('session');
    }
});
App.SessionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.get('store').find('session', params.session_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you `console.log` your params? seems like this should work.

Comment: I tried... it doesn't get printed at all (maybe this is the problem?)

Comment: yes, are you sure you are using `hash` in your router? maybe its just `localhost/sessions/4` using `history`

Comment: yeah... I even click "Enter" on the address bar (just refresh it)

Comment: May be it just needs to be `this.resource` instead of `this.route`

Answer (score 0):

For the [dynamic segments](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) to work, you need to use `this.resource` when declaring your routes:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("sessions", { path: "/sessions" });
    this.resource("session", { path: "/sessions/:session_id" });
}
```

Comment: didn't help.
Additional info the error happens after:Transition #0: session: calling deserialize hook ember.js:3911
Error while processing route: session Assertion Failed: You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method Error: Assertion Failed: You may not pass `undefined` as id to the store's find method